# Installing Python 2 and 3 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, windows-7-x64

I have Python 3.4, and now need to install Python 2.7.  The installer for 2.7 stalls due to an error.  Has anyone successfully installed 2.7 when they already have 3.4 installed and is there something more I should do than simply  goint to they Python.org site?

Comment: There are not nearly enough details here. You can install as many versions of Python as you want.

Comment: What kind of errors did your installer give you? kindly provide that also.

Comment: The installer gave a very generic "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.  A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected.  Contact your support personnel or package vendor."  As indicated later, I renamed the C:\Python34 directory temporarily and that allowed me to install Python27.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and had exactly that on my PC. No funny steps or anything. They install to different folders anyway (Python27 and Python34).

Comment: Hi Lloyd.  Thanks for your response.  Just knowing that it should be possible was very helpful.  I ended up renaming my C:\Python34 to C:\TPython34 before installing Python27.  This worked, and now I do have both working.  I still have a remaining issue in that I can only use Python27 if I rename the Python34 directory something else while I do that work.

I suspect this is because when

Comment: One way around it could be to install them to different folders if this is causing the system grief. Try that